# Eclipse not compiling .jsp file to _jsp.java and _jsp.class to Catalina

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have a file_B.jsp that is quite happily referenced to in the web.xml file

```
   <action name="File_B" helper-class="name.of.helper.fileHelper">
       <result name="default"   web-page="/path/to/jsp/directory/file_B.jsp" screen-name="File B" screen-id="file_b" />
   </action>
```

And it is safely within C:\Users\myDirectory\workspace\webusr\WebContent\WEB-INF\conf\sub\directory

[Trust me - there are several dozens of other jsp files mapped out this way :-) ]

But come runtime the browser throws up a 404.

I checked in the directories under Catalina and there is no file_B_jsp.java nor file_B_jsp.class.

Now, I know the mistake I made. I did a copy/pasta from file_A.jsp (80% of the code and structure is the same).

I did a simple test and had eclipse make a NewFile.jsp and changed web.xml to

```
<action name="File_B" helper-class="name.of.helper.fileHelper">
       <result name="default"   web-page="/path/to/jsp/directory/NewFile.jsp" screen-name="File B" screen-id="file_b" />
```

and sure enough the browser could find it. And there were a NewFile_jsp.java and NewFile_jsp.class inside Catalina

So I copied the code from the file_B.jsp. Deleted the file_B.jsp, had eclipse make a new file_B.jsp and pasted the code back in. Put web.xml back to pointing to the file_B.jsp. Stopped the server. Cleaned it and started it again.

But still the browser says 404, as there is still no file_B_jsp.java nor file_B_jsp.class.

I absolutely need to have file_B.jsp named "file_B.jsp". The whole system is based on this naming convention (decades old legacy at an electrical power company)

What file inside of eclipse needs to be manually edited? Or can I just make a new Tomcat server on the development machine?

Comment: I've tried throwing out the old Tomcat server and making a new one. Still no file_B_jsp.java nor file_B_jsp.class files. The NewFile_jsp.java and NewFile_jsp.class files were removed from the directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some inside eclipse was misaligned. Either building a new server or running yet another clean or switching out of the workspace and switching back into the workspace got eclipse to start compiling the file_B_jsp.java and file_B_jsp.class inside of Catalina.